# Separate letters in image c#

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, aforge

I have images with 6 letters and I wish to separte it into 6 images with 1 letter each.
I was using this function:

```
public static List<UnmanagedImage> ApplyBlobExtractor (UnmanagedImage unmanaged)
        {
            // Extract blobs
            BlobCounter blobCounter  = new BlobCounter ();
            blobCounter.ObjectsOrder = ObjectsOrder.XY;
            blobCounter.ProcessImage (unmanaged);

            // Add blobs into list
            Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjects (unmanaged, false);
            List<UnmanagedImage> unmanagedList = new List<UnmanagedImage> (blobs.Length);
            foreach (Blob blob in blobs)
                unmanagedList.Add (blob.Image);

            return unmanagedList;
        }
```

The problem is that sometimes the letters are touching each other and this make the function recognize the 2 letters as a single one. Is there a way to improve my function or create a better one?

This is an example of image that is giving wrong result:
[image]

The function is giving me 2 images instead of 6.

Image 1 :[image]

Image 2:[image]

Comment: Trying to defeat captcha? This will be a tough one.

Comment: @kadzu Set a threshold of max letter width. In your example you said that you got 2 images instead of 6. Now take each of the 2 sets - which should be, of course, more than the max letter threshold - and work with them in a different way. Maybe erosion and then again blob counter? Just play around with morphological image operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use clustering methods as a start.

A quick test with python's [scikit spectral clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#spectral-clustering) gives me this result:

[image]

I don't know what exists in C# though.